# Show a submenu but hide its parent menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im trying to reveal a submenu but hide its main menu but i cant seem to get the back link to work.

Heres the js im using :

```
$('.menu-item-has-children').click(function() { 
  $(this).find(".sub-menu").addClass('show');
  $(this).parent().addClass('hide');
});

    $('.back').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().removeClass('show');
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().removeClass('hide');
    });
```

Heres a fiddle, when clicking the back link it doesnt seem to remove and add the classes like it should.

http://jsfiddle.net/ukscotth/rh2brt6m/2/

Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/F5kg7/50/  to to just target the back button you'll need `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Ive worked out that when i click the back button its also running the code from when i click the menu item itself, any way to just target the back button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have just found out, your click handler for menu item is getting triggered when you click the back button.  What you need to do is stop the event bubbling up back to your menu item..

So try ->

```
$('.back').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
```

Another problem I also see is you really have some invalid markup there,  an A tag really shouldn't be a child of a `UL`, it works but I've a feeling invalid markup may give you different results on different browsers.  So I suggest you place your `A` tag inside another `<LI>` element and just do another parent..  Or to make things like this easier, I would use `closest` instead.

Comment: Thanks. It still seems to bubble up even after i add that. Any ideas ?

Comment: Not really sure as that's all I did to your fiddle and it seems to work -> http://jsfiddle.net/83o2vm2b/1/   PS,.. I'm using Chrome, and if your using a different browsers, it might be the invalid markup I also pointed out.

Comment: Thanks, yours works for me, I must of done something wrong. Yours works well though, thanks for that. I just need to work out how to make it work on sub sub menus now lol